# How do you add textViews to a Constraint Layout programmatically, connect ones start with the other's end without leaving space between?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have been trying to add textViews to my constraint layout programmatically, however, even when I set the horizontal bias to be 0, the textViews have huge gaps between one another. When I add set the horizontal bias to be 0 in the xml files however, this gap is not there. [How the layout looks when the extra textViews are added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqLn5.png)

I am trying to have them like this:
[How the layout looks when the textViews are added via XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBy4q.png)

My code is the following for adding a textView:

```
    TextView tx = new TextView(this);
    tx.setText(eventName);
    tx.setTextSize(15);
    tx.setId(View.generateViewId());
    eventsAdded.add(tx.getId());
    tx.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    tx.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    tx.setShadowLayer(1,1,1,getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    constraintLayout.addView(tx);

    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.connect(tx.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,topOf.getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    constraintSet.connect(tx.getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,bottomOf.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP);
    if (index == 0) {
        constraintSet.connect(tx.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,separatorBar.getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
    }else{
        constraintSet.connect(tx.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,eventsAdded.get(index),ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
    }
    constraintSet.connect(tx.getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
    if(bias!=0){
        constraintSet.setVerticalBias(tx.getId(),(float)bias);
    }else{
        constraintSet.setVerticalBias(tx.getId(),0);
    }
    constraintSet.constrainHeight(tx.getId(),dpToPx(duration));
    constraintSet.constrainWidth(tx.getId(),dpToPx(60));
    constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(tx.getId(),(float)0);
    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
    index++;
```

Edit: It appears this may be a bug with ConstraintSet not honouring Horizontal Bias input but honouring vertical Bias. I will update this when a fix comes out.
(Check comments for link to issue)

Comment: Have you tried modifying padding and margin?
Also, you would have much better control if you wrap your textViews in ListView or RecycleView

Comment: @Gotiasits I tried modifying the padding and margins but no matter the changes, the views stayed fixed apart from one another. You mean wrap each textView in an individual ListView or RecycleView or all of them in the same one?

Comment: If you put them individually you're left with the same problem.
If your testing device has that option, you can turn on "Show Layout Boundaries" under Developer Options. That might give you a clue...

Comment: I have found that the constraint layout allows me a lot of control vertically, allowing me to easily move the textViews very slightly up and down to reflect how where they should be on the time scale (see images in the post). I have not found this as easy in recycler or list views. As such, I would like to keep them in the constraint layout, but figure out why the distance between them is there on the horizontal axis, and how to fix it.

Comment: This may be an issue with setting left/right constraints with ConstraintSet. See this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62154545).

Comment: @Cheticamp this is the exact issue I am having at the moment. Damn. Gotta wait for a fix then I suppose.

Comment: Try using start/end instead of left/right. It should work.

Comment: @Cheticamp Still the same issue with start and end instead of left right.

Comment: You could have multiple issues.

Comment: @Cheticamp they should only be to do with the constraintSet input shown as this is the only difference between adding the textViews via XML or programmatically.